# In IIS, why doesn't Window Authentication show up as one of the options for my web application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-authentication

I'm reading about [how to set up windows authentication for my web application on IIS 7](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs). In the description they have Window Authentication as an option in IIS.
[image]

I have Windows authentication turned on for my machine (I'm on Windows 7 Professional 64bit) and I still don't see it as one of the authentication options for my web application. Why?

[image]
[image]

I have tried disabling Anonymous Authentication as well, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you stopped and started IIS? Restarted the box etc? You should have it in the list as far as I can see.

Comment: @starskythehutch  damn it, that was it. I swear I restarted my machine after enabling windows authentication. After restarting my machine windows authentication does show up in the list.

Comment: FYI: After installing IIS features iisreset is sufficient. You don't have to reboot the computer.

Answer (score 73):

I had to run IIS Manager as an administrator to resolve this.

Comment: I didn't even have to restart my computer, I just restarted *Internet Information Services Manager* and it appeared.

Answer (score 18):

I stumbled upon this, but couldn’t find Security feature under “Turn Windows feature on or off”.

In Windows Server 2008 R2, this is located under Server Manager -> Roles -> Web Server (IIS) -> Add Role Services.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question OP has asked. They don't need to know where to go to install it.

Answer (score 8):

You can fix this by stopping and restart IIS.

Answer (score 8):

in Windows Server 2012,
Server Manager > Roles > Web Server (IIS) > Security > install windows authentication

reopen IIS

Comment: This doesn't answer the question OP asked. They don't need to know where to go to install it.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in my windows 7 professional. I found that the "Windows Authentication" option was not enabled from "Turn windows feature on and off".

Open "Turn windows feature on and off" window. The "Windows Authentication" option is available under Internet Information services" -> World wide web services -> security. Click the check box for "Windows Authentication".  More information is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/providers/add

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked. They don't need to know where to go to install it.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Server 2022, go to "Server Manager" -> "Add roles and features"

Web Server (IIS) -> Web Server -> Security -> Windows Authentication

Answer (score -1):

Windows Server 2016, IIS 10: Restart the IIS management tool.