# There is no Windows authentication option in my IIS 10.0, how can i add it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis-8

There is no Windows authentication in my Internet Information Services (IIS) 10.0 
[image]

also i don't find it in the windows features as in the picture 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In IIS, why doesn't Window Authentication show up as one of the options for my web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067448/in-iis-why-doesnt-window-authentication-show-up-as-one-of-the-options-for-my-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely not supported in the version of Window that you have installed.

Comment: I think that is true, i use windows 10 home 
which version should i use , and what can i do to fix that in my version new ?

Comment: You need Pro or Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Home edition does not support Windows Authentication. If you upgrade to Windows 10 Pro (or run your IIS in a VM), you should find it.