# IIS missing option for Windows Authentication BUT also missing from add windows features

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, windows-authentication

I found a link that told me that in order to get IIS to display Windows Authentication option for my website, I need to Add the feature in using windows...(link below).
The problem is, I do not see that option....Screenshot shown.
[image: Picture is Here]Any ideas?

Prior related question tells you to add the feature:

[In IIS, why doesn't Window Authentication show up as one of the options for my web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067448/in-iis-why-doesnt-window-authentication-show-up-as-one-of-the-options-for-my-w)

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: if you are using windows 10 home or SL version when might be you are unable to see Windows Authentication under IIS.