# Windows authentication doesn't work after deploy on iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, iis

I have a problem with this simple piece of code:

```
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
        ClaimsIdentity identity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        string userName = identity.Name;  //!!!

        _logger.Trace("windows user `{0}` is trying to access the system", userName);
        var admins = _configurationRoot.GetSection(ConfigDescription.Admins).Get<List<string>>();
        if (!admins.Contains(userName)) 
        {
            _logger.Trace("Permission denied.");
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("/error/unauthorized", false);
        }
    }
```

When I launch my `asp net` app via `IIS Express` in `Visual Studio` everything works fine. My logs in this case:

```
2021-12-25 22:02:53.1783 TRACE     windows user `Domain\username` is trying to access the system.
```

But `userName` is always empty after publishing on remote IIS.

```
2021-12-25 19:11:55.2524 TRACE     windows user `` is trying to access the system.
2021-12-25 19:11:55.2524 TRACE     Permission denied.
```

[image]

I was trying open website from localhost and via domain name, also added it into Trusted Sites, nothing helped.

`web.config` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" arguments=".\BlaBla.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Anonymous Authentication is enabled on IIS

[image]

Because if not, I can't open even `error/unauthorized` page like this:

[image]

Comment: Anonymous authentication cannot be left enabled.

Comment: @user9938 I don't use database. Administrators names are stored in json config. But problem is `userName` variable is empty.

Comment: @LexLi Otherwise I just can't open any page. Please see last screen.

Comment: It's going to be lengthy if I explain everything about Windows authentication, so I won't tell other than some key things. 1) If you want to use it, then quite a few settings are required https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#iis 2) Your ASP.NET Core code must also be changed accordingly. 3) 401 error can be expected if your browser does not send credentials. How to troubleshoot that is another huge topic you can learn from existing threads.

Comment: Not sure I understand how to change my code, anyway thanks for 1) and 2) options. About №3) - I added site into Trusted Sites in Internet Explorer browser, so i don't think the problem is in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable windows authentication in IIS need to make sure the followings

1. Enable Windows Authentication in IIS
2. Enable Windows Authentication in IIS web application

**1. Enable Windows Authentication in IIS**

we need to enable Windows Authentication in “Windows features” (Run command : ***optionalfeatures . Win + R → optionalfeatures***)

[image]

**2. Enable Windows Authentication in IIS web application**

Then we need to Enable windows authentication for applications. Can be done in web.config as below or in IIS

web.config

```xml
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

IIS

Select the application in left node and select "Authentication" in feature view
[image]

Enable Windows Authentication and Disable anonymous Authentication.

[image]

More information

1. [IIS Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/)
2. [Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#iis)

Comment: Question about your last screen: what if I have only one option like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAbAu.png).

Comment: @Сергей it seems IIS is not configured with Windows authentication. Please make sure you have enabled "Windows Authentication" as in the first step. (Refer to first screenshot)

Comment: As far as I see, `Windows Authentication` [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxhBJ.png)

Comment: @Сергей Did you try restarting IIS? please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067448/in-iis-why-doesnt-window-authentication-show-up-as-one-of-the-options-for-my-w

Comment: well, looks like all I needed to do was restart [server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjvgl.png)